# Installation of GIT Equivalent of Visual SVN

Tags: git, github

I am an SVN user and we are using visual SVN for the version control. Now I have to shift to GIT.

When I installed SVN, I only needed to install the visual SVN on my server.

My questions are :

- What should I do for setting up GIT?
- Should I install Github for Desktop?
- Or is the only option to install GIT for Windows?
- Is there some GUI utility of GIT?

**Note:**

I will have more then fifty users and a server on which it will be installed.

Comment: Isn't there already git support included in current visual studio versions?

Comment: VISUAL SVN Is not something related to visual studio. It is client of svn

Comment: VisualSVN is an extension for Visual Studio that integrates SVN into the IDE. VisualSVN Server is the Subversion server package for Windows. Just wanted to make a note about that to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

> is there some GUI utility of GIT

[git gui clients](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis/)

Personally, I find GitKraken quite convenient to use.

I would recommend taking a look at [Pro Git book by Scott Chacon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484200772).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) if you want to organize multiple repositories, but nearly every IDE has a git client already installed, like Visual Studio, Eclipse or products from Jetbrains. So you could use that and have no need for an extra tool.

If you want to have a central server with git it would be enough to just install git and run

```
git --bare init
```

For more information you might watch at the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).